# Can I use SysAllocString in sub thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, com

I have a main thread and two sub threads. When these two sub threads both use ::SysAllocString to allocate memory at the same time, it get deadlocked. And this situation can't show up all the time because I can't ensure they always allocate memory at the same time. There are my question：

1. Can I use SysAllocString in sub thread?
2. Is SysAllocString a thread safety function? If not, What should I do to avoid deadlock?

[image]

[image]
This is the first thread's call stack, officespace.dll is my own DLL module, and I wonder why there is a WinMTExt.dll and Lang.dll calling. There is a WinMount program on the computer.

[image]
This is the second thread's call stack, excelrw.dll is my own DLL module, and I have added ::CoInitialize(NULL) and ::CoUninitialize() in this thread, why does it still call loadLibrary?

Comment: `SysAllocString` is believed to be thread safe (its internal allocator is documented as thread safe in MSDN), you should be looking for deadlock cause somewhere else, not exactly this API and memory allocation.

Comment: I have checked the callstack, it shows the two thread both waiting for this function return. And when calling SysAllocString, the two thread both called  kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryExW@12()  + 0xc8 bytes , does this cause the deadlock?

Comment: Yes. A lOadLibrary call can cause a deadlock. But SysAllocString Usually never loads DLLs. Are you using an IMallcoSpy. Show us more of the callstack in your question.

Comment: If you have call stacks, just post them in full here (and after loading symbol information).

Comment: SysAllocString() should never cause LoadLibrary() to be called.  When it does, you have a very strong hint that you forgot to initialize COM.  Not optional when you make COM runtime support calls.  You *must* call CoInitializeEx() in each thread.

Comment: The callstack is too long...My reputation can't put an image here. But I think what Hans Passant said is possible. I found out one thread had called CoInitialize, but the others didn't.

Comment: Still, I wonder why SysAllocString would require COM initialization. The memory allocation functions of COM may be called before COM is initialized on a thread (this probably helps to avoid some chicken-and-egg problems).

Comment: @MSalters: It might not require and instead attempt to initialize mandatory stuff itself. Then it might cause a deadlock for a reason not yet revealed by the problem description (e.g. the poster does certain actions right from `DllMain`). Apparently the problem is not about `SysAllocString` exactly.

Comment: @RomanR.: It can't initialize COM, as it wouldn't know whether you require STA or MTA. But yeah, no minimal example.

Comment: Well, let's think of it this way. You don't know how to initialize COM yet... then why would you need to allocate strings with `SysAllocString()` instead of with something else?